# R reticulate: how can I close/restart the python console

Tags: python, r, reticulate

After `source_python` to get the result, can I close or restart the python console? If so, how?

And suppose I closed/restarted the python console, would I still be able to access  in R the variables and functions that were created in `source_python` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't believe this is possible. Your issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/27).

Quoting @jjallaire (one of the devs, and CEO of RStudio): "No, you can't safely unload and reload the connection to Python (too many unreversable side effects in the Python interpreter)".

Restarting the python connection requires restarting R.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly clear about this. I get that it's not possible to unload then reload, what about simply unload(close) python to release memory?

Comment: Well, you can unload the `reticulate` package: `detach('package:reticulate', unload = TRUE)`. I'm not sure if this would release the memory held by python. I did notice that reloading `reticulate` after unloading causes it to malfunction, confirming @jjallaire 's statement.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to start and stop python seamlessly in R using the reticulate library. To **start** use `reticulate::repl_python()` and to **close** use `quit`. It seems that even after you quit, the python environment persists, so if you re-open python any variables you created before in python are still there. Therefore, to my knowledge, it doesn't seem as though you can restart the python console.

This thread is a bit old, but I wanted to leave an answer for those coming here more recently. Also this is the first result when googling how to end python reticulate sessions. The answer I posted works for me and here are my version details: R - 4.3.1, python - 3.9.18, reticulate - 1.32.0. I'm not sure if this answer works for older versions.